# Travis could not find gem

Tags: rubygems, travis-ci

I have this in gemfile

```
------
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1"
------
```

And travis give me this https://travis-ci.org/ArseniyAndru/adverts/builds/13230896

Could not find paperclip-dropbox-1.1.6 in any of the sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the author has deleted the `1.1.6` release from Rubygems (for whatever reason), so Travis won't find it. ([paperclip-dropbox on Rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-dropbox))

He has published a `1.1.7` release however, so if you run `$ bundle update` or `$ bundle update paperclip-dropbox` locally, commit the changes and redeploy, Travis will install `1.1.7`.